# Is it bad to use wrong measurement system with a particular English style

Tags: questions

We have two major English styles: American English (AmE) and British English (BrE).

If I use AmE in a question, should I also stick to the system of measurement that most Americans use (Fahrenheit scale, pounds, feet etc.)? Or can I use the SI system (kilogram, Celsius scale<sup>1</sup> etc.)?

---

<sup>1</sup> No, Celsius isn't in the SI system, but AFAIK no one uses kelvin in everyday life.

Comment: It just depends whether you want to be understood or not.

Comment: (Well done on not writing "degrees Kelvin" though!)

Comment: I don't think it matters what units you use, but you need to be consistent. I saw a post where someone mixed metric and imperial units (something of the flavour of *kg per square foot*) and tried to say they were using SI units. Someone else pointed out the discrepancy in comments. (Sorry, I don't have a link handy.) So long as you're consistent, you should be fine - especially on a language site. It doesn't really affect the grammar, for example, whether you say "It shifted about 5cm through the snow" or "It shifted about 2 inches through the snow".

Comment: Yes, the degree Celsius is in the SI, it is in fact the unit of Celsius temperature. See https://www.bipm.org/metrology/thermometry/units.html

Comment: @AndrewLeach - If we're going to be that picky about the names of temperature units, then we shouldn't be capitalizing *kelvins*. The Kelvin scale, yes; units within that scale, no.

Comment: And if you choose to use both units, make sure you have the same precision in both. Example, "about 25 miles (40 km)" is OK, but I see things like "about 25 miles (40.233 km)" which irk me to no end.

Comment: FWIW, there is an energy drink named Celsius, a vodka named Absolut, and a men's perfume from Dior named Fahrenheit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The purpose of language is to communicate, so use whichever measurements your audience is most likely to understand. Even though you are writing in American English, your audience may expect metric measurements based on the subject matter.

I could write an article about the London Stock Exchange for an American audience and favor putting prices in US dollars instead of pounds or euros because that is what my audience understands best.